# Set spinner value position on performclick

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have spinner having value from 1-50.

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinnerSel"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:layout_weight="0.4"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:gravity="right"
   android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

By default no any selected value. So, i have set it's selection to 0.

```
spin.setSelection(0);
```

Now, when user `performClick` then spinner open selection dropdown and i want it to start from 20. 
Means on click default dropdown position start from 20. Then user can scroll to up or down and change the value.

I search lots but, didn't get any idea regarding that.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: try setonclick listener and put `spin.setSelection(20);` in it.

Comment: setOnClick listner did not work for that

Answer (score 1):

try below code!

```
spin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    spin.setSelection(20);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Nice solution. But, there is one problem. If i don't select any value and close dropdown then it default set to 20.

Answer (score 0):

It is nice to use Shrenik Shah's answer. But for default item use this.

```
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                      String myString = "Select one"; //the value you want the position for

                      ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spin.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter

                      int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);

                      //set the default according to value
                      spin.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
                }
            });
```

plus Shrenik Shah's answer.

```
spin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    spin.setSelection(20);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

> Note: We can not use a null as default selection. We must add some values for
>   that like "Select One".

Comment: Thanks CoDFather. But onNothingSelected does not called. When i click out side spinner. I have selected on nothing. `setSelection(0)`